# Add Column to Query From Same Table, Update Values in Duplicated Column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure this one out. In this scenario, gas prices from a particular city in this database are increasing, so they will need to raise their prices 20%. I'm supposed to create a query that will display what the new price will be from that city only. Here is what it is supposed to look like:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Select ProductID, tblProduct.ProductType, Price, SUM((Price *.20)+Price) AS 'Increased Price'
From tblProduct join tblCompany
    On tblProduct.CompanyID = tblCompany.CompanyID
Where tblCompany.CompanyID IN
    (Select CompanyID
    From tblCompany
    Where City = 'Kalamazoo')
Order By ProductID
```

However, when I go to execute the code, I get the following error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'tblProduct.ProductID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: Remove the `SUM`. You want to add 20% to the current `Price`, not compute for the `SUM` of all rows.

Comment: If you use aggregate function with a column, the other columns you are selecting should be used in groupby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont really need the SUM function if you are only calculating the 20% price increase...Do this instead

```
Select ProductID, tblProduct.ProductType, Price, ((Price *.20)+Price) AS 'Increased Price'
From tblProduct join tblCompany
    On tblProduct.CompanyID = tblCompany.CompanyID
Where tblCompany.CompanyID IN
    (Select CompanyID
    From tblCompany
    Where City = 'Kalamazoo')
Order By ProductID
```

Comment: That fixed my problem of not getting anything to compute, but my prices are off for some reason. They're actually higher than what the picture above says they're supposed to be.

Comment: which particular row is doing that? example?

Comment: In order, the prices column has the following values:
996.00,
1188.00,
690.00,
912.00,
990.00,
468.00,
29.28,
24.54,
19.80,
16.20,

The increased prices column is calculating that accordingly, but the prices column doesn't match what the picture says the values should be.

Comment: yes i understand..what does the query above give you thats off?

Comment: The values from the Prices column should match what's in the picture, but the values that are there are the values that should be in the "Increased Prices" Column. The values in the Prices column should be 20% less than what they currently are.

Comment: then just do this `(Price - (Price * 20))`  or `(0.80 * Price)`

Comment: That still doesn't work for some reason. Frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select tblProduct.ProductID, tblProduct.ProductType, tblProduct.Price, SUM((tblProduct.Price *.20)+tblProduct.Price) AS 'Increased Price'
From tblProduct join tblCompany
    On tblProduct.CompanyID = tblCompany.CompanyID
Where tblCompany.CompanyID IN
    (Select c.CompanyID
    From tblCompany c
    Where c.City = 'Kalamazoo')
Order By ProductID
```

Answer (score 0):

The `SUM()` suggests an aggregation query.  You have no `GROUP BY`, so the initial columns (`ProductId`, etc.) are not valid.

It is a good idea to use table aliases for queries.  These make queries easier to write and to read.  So:

```
Select p.ProductID, p.ProductType, p.Price, ((p.Price * 1.20) AS IncreasedPrice
From tblProduct p join
     tblCompany c
     On p.CompanyID = c.CompanyID
Where c.City = 'Kalamazoo'
Order By p.ProductID;
```

In addition, the `IN` clause is unnecessary.  You can just check the city using the `JOIN`.